# Wordwrap not working correctly with NavMenu and Div

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, angular

I created a ASP.Net Core Web Application with Angular in VS2017.
The initial application word wraps the way I want.
However after I added some HTML and styles the word wrap no longer works when the left panel is showing.

I found that the following HTML

```
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum</p>

<div class="container">
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum</p>
</div>
```

causes the following display
[image]

How do I fix the effect of the Div?

Comment: It would be helpful to see the related html structure and CSS. Also mention if you are using any frame works.

Comment: Thanks @crazymatt I updated the question

Comment: Awesome! Anyway we could see the output of the code in question? Could you copy/paste that section here from your source code?

Comment: Do you mean View Source? that is huge

Comment: haha not the entire thing just the section where the text is having the wrapping issue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of using

```
<div class="container">
```

I needed to use

```
<div class="container-fluid">
```

Answer (score 0):

Try adding this css for wordwrap

```
h2 {
    white-space: normal;}
```

Comment: Thanks. I tried adding that to h2 but it made no difference.